# Unable to get access token when using Workload Identity in GKE (.NET)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

I have set up the Workload Identity on a GKE cluster, and now I am using a Kubernetes SA linked to an IAM SA with appropriate permissions. I checked that when I use the IAM SA key file, it gets the access I need.

However, it gets weird even when following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

The first suggested check is to run this command to check the metadata server response:

```
$ curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email

<sa_name>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

So far, so good. The next paragraph that describes using the Quota Project option suggests using another command, which should return the identity token. And it fails:

```
$ curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 404 Not Found: Not found; Gaia id not found for email <sa_name>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The same happens when I use the .NET SDK and call this:

```
var oidcToken1 = await cc.GetOidcTokenAsync(
    OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(_serviceUrl),
    cancellationToken
);

_addToken = async (request, token) => {
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Bearer",
        await oidcToken1.GetAccessTokenAsync(cancellationToken: token)
    );
};
```

The code works fine when I use the IAM SA JSON key, but when it runs in the pod that uses the Workload Identity, I get the same message as before:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential Token has expired, trying to get a new one.
Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler Request[00000001] (triesRemaining=3) URI: 'http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://<service_url>&format=full'
Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler Response[00000001] Response status: NotFound 'Not Found'
Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler Response[00000001] An abnormal response wasn't handled. Status code is NotFound
```

The same happens when I use `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` from the Workload Identity test pod:

> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/<sa_name>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb'Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 404 Not Found: Not found; Gaia id not found for email <sa_name>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7feabe712910>)

I am not sure what else can be done; it seems like the whole thing just doesn't work.

Comment: I've not used Workload Identity with GKE but your question may be the opportunity for me to try it unless you identify the solution sooner; I still mount IAM Service Account keys as Secrets (but appreciate I should "evolve"). In my long (worked at Google in Cloud 2013-2018 and continue using it after Google) experience with Google Cloud, things *do* work but -- as with this -- it can be a tortuous series of steps. I encourage you to revisit the steps and ensure you're not mis-stepping. It would be helpful if Google provide scripts for some of these processes.

Comment: I think it doesn't apply here but the only time I recall a similar issue was when the OAuth scopes were incorrectly (insufficient) configured on a VM but this should not be possible when GKE is programming the VMs. It's *possible* that a bug and a misconfiguration are hiding a 403 from the underlying Metadata service and surfacing this as a 400 from the GKE Metadata service proxy.

Comment: I think I will open a support ticket with GCP.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. I made an idiotic mistake and mistyped the IAM service account name configured in the Kubernetes service account annotation.

Google support provided troubleshooting guidelines, which I followed, and there it is important to use the output of the previous command as the input for the next, if applicable. When I tried to describe the IAM service account using the value from the Kubernetes service account annotation, I got "SA not found" error, which gave me a clue to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it. This is why I provided a script in my proposed answer and why I think Google should provide scripts when programming multiple disconnected Cloud resources. Using a script, one can more readily refactor variables to reuse these in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either misconfigured a step (the Service Account stuff is especially gnarly) or [you're experiencing a car accident](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Fw8TVYBKg).

I am unable to repro your issue. It works for me.

```bash
BILLING="[YOUR-BILLING-ACCOUNT]"

Q="74552713"
PROJECT=$(whoami)-$(date +%y%m%d)-${Q}

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

POOL="${PROJECT}.svc.id.goog"

CLUSTER_PROJECT="${PROJECT}"
CLUSTER_NAME="cluster"
CLUSTER_LOCATION="us-west1-c"

# Gets the latest RAPID version
CLUSTER_VERSION=$(\
  gcloud container get-server-config \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --zone=${CLUSTER_LOCATION} \
  --flatten=channels \
  --filter=channels.channel=RAPID \
  --format="value(channels.validVersions[0])")

# My go-to test cluster config w/ workload-pool
gcloud beta container clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
--spot \
--no-enable-basic-auth \
--cluster-version=${CLUSTER_VERSION} \
--release-channel="rapid" \
--machine-type="e2-standard-2" \
--image-type="COS_CONTAINERD" \
--metadata=disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
--num-nodes=1 \
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,GcePersistentDiskCsiDriver \
--enable-ip-alias \
--enable-autoupgrade \
--enable-autorepair \
--enable-managed-prometheus \
--enable-shielded-nodes \
--enable-vertical-pod-autoscaling \
--shielded-secure-boot \
--shielded-integrity-monitoring \
--no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
--max-surge-upgrade=1 \
--max-unavailable-upgrade=0 \
--node-locations=${CLUSTER_LOCATION} \
--zone=${CLUSTER_LOCATION} \
--project=${CLUSTER_PROJECT} \
--workload-pool=${POOL}

# Implicit
# gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER_NAME} ...

# Test that cluster's workloadPool matches expected value
GOT=$(\
  gcloud container clusters describe ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --zone=${CLUSTER_LOCATION} \
  --project=${CLUSTER_PROJECT} \
  --format="value(workloadIdentityConfig.workloadPool)")

WANT="${POOL}"
[ "${GOT}" == "${WANT}" ] && echo "true" || echo "false"

# Kubernetes == Google Cloud Service Account name
ACCOUNT="tester"

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

NAMESPACE="${Q}"

kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE}

kubectl create serviceaccount ${ACCOUNT} \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Redundant for the purpose of this test
ROLE="roles/cloudprofiler.agent"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member="serviceAccount:${EMAIL}" \
--role="${ROLE}"

# Allow Kubernetes robot to impersonate Cloud robot
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${EMAIL} \
--role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
--member "serviceAccount:${PROJECT}.svc.id.goog[${NAMESPACE}/${ACCOUNT}]"

# Updated IAM policy for serviceAccount [{EMAIL}].
# bindings:
# - members:
#   - serviceAccount:{PROJECT}.svc.id.goog[{NAMESPACE}/{ACCOUNT}]
#   role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
# etag: BwXuOwsx9lk=
# version: 1

# Annotate Service Account
kubectl annotate serviceaccount ${ACCOUNT} \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=${EMAIL}

# Update Pod specs
# spec:
#   serviceAccountName: {ACCOUNT}
#   nodeSelector:
#     iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"


POD="workload-identity-test"

echo "
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: \"${POD}\"
  namespace: \"${NAMESPACE}\"
spec:
  containers:
  - image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
    name: \"${POD}\"
    command: [\"sleep\",\"infinity\"]
  serviceAccountName: \"${ACCOUNT}\"
  nodeSelector:
    iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: \"true\"
" | kubectl apply --filename=-


# Test that proxied (!) Metadata Service Account email matches
GOT=$(\
  kubectl exec \
  --stdin --tty \
  ${POD} \
  --namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  -- /bin/bash -c 'curl --header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email')

WANT="${EMAIL}"
[ "${GOT}" == "${WANT}" ] && echo "true" || echo "false"

# Demonstrate that access-token is obtained
kubectl exec \
--stdin --tty \
${POD} \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
-- /bin/bash -c 'curl --header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token' \
| jq -r .access_token[0:15]
# ya29.c.b0Aa9Vdy
```

Comment: I don't know how exactly the cluster was configured, but we do have all the nodes annotated with `iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"`. I also assume that if the metadata server returns a proper email, it "kind of" works, but the token can't be obtained. So, my question is: when the metadata server returns the impersonated SA email, but not returning the access token, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

One additional check (just to complement other answers) besides the previously stated issues, I'd suggest being very careful with how you name the Kubernetes Service Account definition vs the Actual service account name.

While implementing this, we name the service account GSA_NAME=`team-api` on GCP, and the Kubernetes definition was named KSA_NAME=`team-api-svc-ac`.

We ended up defining the policy as

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/GSA_NAME]"
```

When it should have been:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME]"
```

You can check out the docs for this example, but this is one of the steps where we can get caught up in the details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to use a non existent service account, double check your service account email so there are no typos.